# Is there a common way of auto-updates with cron?

Tags: apt, cron, unattended-upgrades

I run Ubuntu and Fedora on a day to day basis and usually run the package manager to check for updates nearly once a day.

When I get a kernel update I usually reboot, so that I'm running on the new kernel and I can see if there are any glitches (It's almost always fine).

If I add

`apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade`

or

`dnf check-update && dnf upgrade`

to my root crontab is there anything procedurally wrong?

What if I set up crontab to do this at 4 a.m. and it installs a new kernel, then I don't reboot and it auto-installs a second new kernel. What if I don't reboot my Ubuntu box for a month and there have been 3 kernel updates and a couple of other patches to the same piece of software during this time?

Is it OK to enable automatic updating this way? I know that there's an 'unattended upgrades' utility for Ubuntu, but I'd rather learn what other system admins do and have a more 'hands on' approach to administering my PC's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, sysadmins with a mixed install base would use a cross-platform configuration management / orchestration system like Puppet, Chef, or Ansible to manage updates.

You could also set up one of those tools on a smaller scale if you like.

Or, on Fedora *, you can use [DNF Automatic](http://dnf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/automatic.html) — see [the Fedora page on configuring this](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/AutoUpdates). This is better than a simple cron script because it has better error handling and more options for output.

For Ubuntu, there are instructions on the community wiki for [automatic updates](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticSecurityUpdates), but I haven't used them so I can't comment more than to just provide the pointer.

* disclosure: I work on Fedora

Comment: Ah, I'm glad I asked before doing it my way! I will check out DNF Automatic and maybe install the Ubuntu equivalent. Not sure if it's worth bothering with config-management for two or three PC's but might do that some day. Question marked answered. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I think unattended-upgrades tool is the way to do so.

It's just a python script with several unattended dpkg options inside, you can take advantages of options concerning reboot in the configuration file /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades  :

> // Automatically reboot *WITHOUT CONFIRMATION* if //  the file
> /var/run/reboot-required is found after the upgrade
> Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "false";
>
> // Automatically reboot even if there are users currently logged in //
> when Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "false";
> //Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot-WithUsers "true";
>
> // If automatic reboot is enabled and needed, reboot at the specific
> // time instead of immediately //  Default: "now"
> //Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot-Time "02:00";

There are some other option to configure the behaviour in much more specific way (only security updates, use extra repositories,etc...) .

https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades

Then you can schedule it using two ways :

- Just put unattended-upgrade in the root's crontab then.
- Use the configuration files to do so.

more info : https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades